# Check if a screen session is running and automating via cron

Tags: linux, cron, grep

So trying to get this to work, not familiar with linux but cobbled this together just having some problems... also the echo ''$NOW' Server was down.... Started !'   ...seems to make to "server was ddown..."etc onto a line below which is weird because if I use the same line in another script the whole thing goes onto 1 line in the servercheck.txt file.

in check.sh >>

```
#!/bin/bash
if screen -list | grep -q "minecraft"; then 
    echo "Server is running!" 
    cd /home/minecraft/ 
    teststart.sh
    NOW=$(date +"%b-%d %H:%M")
    echo ''$NOW'  Server was down.... Started !' >> /home/minecraft/servercheck.txt;
else 
    echo "Server dead" 
fi
```

errors...

```
: not found: check.sh:
Server is running!
: not found: check.sh: teststart.sh
: not found: check.sh:
```

And how to run teststart.... also the: not found:  errors

this has to go into a cron aswel for the user minecraft, any help with that aswel wanting it to run every 5mins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
if screen -list | grep -q "minecraft";
```

you're only checking if the screen is running, not the server. Instead you can use something like

```
ps -ef | grep -i bukkit | grep -v grep; echo $?
```

If return is 0 the (bukkit) server is running if return is 1 the server is not running.

To remove the \n after $NOW use

```
echo -ne ''$NOW'  Server was down.... Started !\n' >> /home/minecraft/servercheck.txt;
```

Comment: ok.. but how to have it run another sh script? right now just checking if the screen is running is fine, my minecraft server seems to crash and take down screen with it, but I might combine the checks

Comment: Use ./teststart.sh instead of teststart.sh after your changed working directory.

Comment: : not found: check.sh: ./teststart.sh  ...doesn't run it at all

Comment: Can you ensure that your line break is \n (linux/unix) and not \r\n (windows).

Comment: its written how it as the top only ./ added infront of it

Comment: fixed it.. it was windows, EOL convertion to UNIX via notepad++ and it works now